# Time complexity summations

Tags: algorithms, time-complexity, asymptotics, summation

How to calculate the time complexity of a algorithm which contains while loops or if statements using summations? I only know how they work with the for loops. And I'm guessing the if loop are calculated as a time complexity of (1)?

```
r=1
for i=6  to n+2
do {
    j=n−3
    while j≥log7(n−1)
    do { 
        j=j−2
        r=2⋅r
        }
    }
```